# Fusing multiple IMUs in EKF framework

Tags: discrete-signals, estimation, kalman-filters, imu, ekf

What is the approach to fuse multiple IMUs in EKF framework?

Normally you take the IMU as the motion model and the sense step to consist of other sensors but when have multiple IMUs operating, what is the correct approach?

Comment: Why do you want to use an EKF framework? What's wrong with just using the standard EKF on each IMU output, and then using a weighted mean of the outputs with the weights based on the stage covariance of each EKF?  That way you can apply known offsets / corrections to each IMU measurement separately before fusing them.

Comment: There is no one approach, or even one uniformly best approach.  You can take @PeterK.'s multiple EKF approach (which, I contend, is _a_ EKF framework).  You could average all of the like outputs of the IMU together, either weighted or not, and treat it as one IMU.  If the IMU's are in significantly different locations you could use the differences in accelerations to determine the rotational acceleration of the vehicle.  Et cetera, et cetera.  It depends on cost, acceptable complexity, what level of mathematical esotericism you can stand, et cetera, et cetera.

Comment: I'm assuming we have a transformation that brings each IMU to a common reference frame.

Comment: The weighted sum isn't a bad idea though,